# I need someone who explain me these lines of code

Tags: c++, stl

I need someone who explain me this code, line by line. I specially don't understand this line:

```
operator std::map<T, U>()
```

Thank you very much.

```
template <typename T, typename U>
class create_map 
{ 
    std::map<T, U> m_map;
public:
    create_map(const T& key, const U& val) 
    {  
        m_map[key] = val;
    }
    create_map<T, U>& operator()(const T& key, const U& val) 
    {
        m_map[key] = val;
        return *this;
    }
    operator std::map<T, U>()     
    {
        return m_map;     
    }
};
```

Comment: Please reformat your code properly (select it in the editor and click the "code" tool-button)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
operator std::map<T, U>()     
{
         return m_map;     
}
```

This is user-defined *conversion* function.

That means, you can write this:

```
//obj is an object of type create_map
create_map<int,std::string> obj(1,"Nawaz");

//obj implicitly converts into std::map type!
std::map<int,std::string> map_inst=obj;
```

---

See this topic to know more about **user-defined conversion function**:

[User Defined Conversions in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3008690/user-defined-conversions-in-c)

You can see this as well: [Implicit conversion sequences (C++ only)](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/comphelp/v8v101/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.xlcpp8a.doc/language/ref/implicit_conversion_sequences.htm)

---

```
create_map<T, U>& operator()(const T& key, const U& val) 
{
      m_map[key] = val;
      return *this;
}
```

This actually overloads the `operator()`, which internally inserts or updates (key,val) pair into the `m_map`; just see the function definition as to what it does.

So using this function you can write code like this,

```
obj(2,"Sarfaraz"); //this inserts the pair into the underlying m_map;
```

I would also suggest you to explore `std::map` a bit more, especially the overloaded `operator[]` in `std::map`.

Comment: sorry i really dont understandthat. i really need an explanation line by line, is really important thank you.

Comment: so it just convert the create_map object to a map object when necessary? and can you explain me please the other operator overloading? and how is it used? im sorry im kind of noob. thank you very much.

Comment: @jose: as a general rule, don't bother telling us that it "is important". It's not important to us. We try to help because we enjoy helping others, but your urgency doesn't really make a difference for us. At best, we'll treat your question the same way we would otherwise, and in the worst case, you'll annoy the people who try to help you, by pushing your urgency onto them. :)

Answer (score 1):

Code:

```
template <typename T, typename U>
class create_map 
{ 
    std::map<T, U> m_map;
public:
    create_map(const T& key, const U& val) 
    {  
        m_map[key] = val;
    }
    create_map<T, U>& operator()(const T& key, const U& val) 
    {
        m_map[key] = val;
        return *this;
    }
    operator std::map<T, U>()     
    {
        return m_map;     
    }
};
```

The purpose of this code is to be able to specify a map with specific key/value pairs, by chaining calls to `operator()`, like

```
create_map<int, std::string>( 1, "blah" )( 2, "hah" )( 3, "doh" )
```

Since the class does not have a default constructor, there's no way to use it to create an empty map. That may be by design. Or it may be a design error.

The

```
operator std::map<T, U>()     
{
    return m_map;     
}
```

defines a conversion to `std::map<T, U>`, which is the end result of it all.

It can be invoked implicitly wherever a `create_map` is specified and a `std::map` is expected, such as using a `create_map` expression as argument in a function call.

However, it can be pretty inefficient since it copies the map. The compiler may well optimize away the copying. But it’s ungood to needlessly rely on Quality Of Implementation (although sometimes that is the best that one can do).

So it should instead be

```
operator std::map<T, U> const& () const
{
    return m_map;     
}
```

The `const` at the end there allows a `create_map` to be declared as `const` and used.

With this conversion to reference there is the same problem as with using reference arguments, namely a theoretical possibility of aliasing, where code that retains a reference to `const` is not prepared to deal with changes of the referred object. But in practice it’s not a problem. For example, as formal argument one just writes `std::string const& s` (instead of just `std::string s`) as a matter of course, and very few if any errors result from that – I’ve never experienced any problem.

Cheers & hth.,

Answer (score 0):

There's not much to understand about it. `operator std::map<T, U>()` overrides the class' conversion operator (which takes no parameters) to provide an object instance of type `std::map<T, U>`. `std::map` is a STL standard class for associative key->value storage. In your case it maps from keys of type `T` to values of type `U`. `T` and `U` have been undefined so far (you wrote `template class`, but where are the template parameters?)

The conversion operator allows to use the class instance in place of the type the operator provides conversion for, like this.

```
class foo {
    operator char const *() {
        return "foo instance as char const *";
    }
};

// ...

void bar(foo &f)
{
    // here the class instance is used as if it were a char const *
    cout << f << endl;
}
```

Comment: @Etienne de Martel, ah, you're right of course. Editing my post accordingly.

Answer (score -1):

The line

```
operator std::map<T, U>()
```

defines a function that will be called when your create_map object is used like an std::map somewhere in the code.

An easier example would be:

```
class A
{
public:
  operator int()
  {
    return 3;
  }
};

int main()
{
  A a;
  cout << a << endl;
}
```

Now the computer finds out that it doesn't know how to print variable a, but it knows how to convert it to an int and then print it. So "3" gets printed.

Comment: And why they put the other overloaded operator in the class???.the constructor doesnt do the same??? im sorry im noob :(.

Comment: Constructor is kinda like the opposite of "operator something()". Constructor allows you to say "A a = 3;"

Comment: please i really need an answer. why they add the other overloaded operator in the class. thank you very much.

Comment: "type operator()(parameters) {...}" allows you to use an object of that class with parentheses. Like this: "create_map a; do_something(a(x, y));". Whereas "operator some_type() {...}" allows you to convert the variable a in "create_map a"; to "some_type". For example: "create_map a; some_type b = a;"

Comment: so they overload the operator () so they can use operator some_type() to convert the variable???

Comment: Let's say you write "create_map m;" Now you have a new object of the type create_map. When you did that, a constructor of your create_map class got called. A constructor is called when a new object is created. Now if you say "something = m(x, y);" the function "create_map...operator()(...)" gets called. The "operator()" function is called every time you use parentheses after your object, like "create_map m; m(1, 2);"

Comment: Don't mix up converting and ()-operator overloading. They are two different things. "operator some_type() {...}" defines the converting to the type some_type, and "some_type operator()(...) {...}" defines what happens if you use parentheses. (Sorry, this wasn't the clearest of explanations..)

Comment: Thank you all. you really helped me.    Kynnysmatto and Nawaz

Comment: when i use this class like this: std::map<int, int> themap = create_map<int, int >(1,2),(5,4); whats happening?

Comment: am i using the constructor twice and the overloaded operator() twice? or am i using the constructor once and the overloaded operator() twice? explain this to me please.

Comment: That won't compile. "type(a),(b)" doesn't mean anything.

Comment: sorry in that statement the statement is like this: create_map<int, int >(1,2)(5,4);   withoutthe comma.

Comment: You are using the constructor once "(1,2)", and then the overloaded operator() once "(5,4)". The syntax "type(parameters)" means calling the constructor and it returns the newly created object. And then you continue by calling the operator() for that object.