# Conversion from my class to int

Tags: c++, casting, type-conversion

I am using a library that is templated and that I do not wish to modify. Namely CImg.
This library has been mostly designed to work with templates of simple types: float, double, int etc.

At some point, this library does:

```
CImg<T>& fill(const T val) {
  if (is_empty()) return *this;
  if (val && sizeof(T)!=1) cimg_for(*this,ptrd,T) *ptrd = val;
  else std::memset(_data,(int)val,size()*sizeof(T));
  return *this;
}
```

Now I want to use this library with a more complex class as template parameter. My particular class is such that `sizeof(T)!=1` and most of the time, the `fill` function will properly assign `val` to each element with the proper `operator=` of my class. However, when `!val`, I would like a conversion operator that allows my class to be cast to an `int` and to produce some values (for example, `0` would make the function above work).

Right now, my program does not compile as it says:

```
error C2440: 'type cast' : cannot convert from 'const MyClass' to 'int'
```

How can I create an operator that allows for `(int)my_variable` with `my_variable` of type `MyClass` to be legal, without modifying the function above ?

Comment: What line is giving that error?  Is it `*ptrd = val;` or is it `fill(myvalue)`?

Comment: it is `std::memset(_data,(int)val,size()*sizeof(T));`  (due to the cast from `val` of type `MyClass` to `int`)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something like this using [user defined conversions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3008690/user-defined-conversions-in-c)

```
int type;
explicit operator int()
{
   return type;
}
```

Comment: thanks as well! It also messes up with my other operators (see below). Any idea? thanks!

Comment: @WhitAngl: It shouldn't be messing up the other operators, and that seems largely unrelated to this question.  Can you make an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) and then post a new question about it with the SSCCE?

Comment: @WhitAngl can you post your other operators?

Comment: thanks ;  I have difficulty accepting an answer that ultimately still results in other errors. I'm preparing an SSCCE.

Comment: here it is : http://codepad.org/icXBM4uz  The error I get is related to the proposed solution, and `explicit` isn't supported either.

Comment: oh, thanks, that was indeed unrelated - sorry for that. Thanks again, I learned a lot!

Answer (score 3):

What you want in this case is probably int conversion operator overload:

```
class A{
    public:

    explicit operator int() const{
        return 2;
    }
};
```

EDIT: 
    |I added explicit conversion that should make your code compile (at least the method you showed us), and not mess-up other operators, but it's only allowed since C++11, so if you are using older compiler it might not be available yet.

Comment: Did you forget about the safe bool idiom?

Comment: I'm not sure he wants a bool conversion, I think he actually wants `int`.

Comment: that seems to work... however, that messes up my other operators (e.g., operator*(MyClass, MyClass) now has a similar conversion with operator*(MyClass, int) ). Any way to force the conversion to be explicit ?

Comment: @WhitAngl: Yes: the safe-bool idiom.

Comment: @MooingDuck what do you mean ?

Comment: @MooingDuck thanks, but what is the relationship with the `int` operator that screws up my other operators? I don't need a bool operator here.

Comment: @WhitAngl Don't define it. You don't need it, and this answer is unsafe.

Comment: @WhitAngl: use the `explicit` keyword

Comment: @MooingDuck I haven't defined the bool operator as I don't need it. And I of course tried `explicit` but this results in `error C2071: 'MyClass::operator int' : illegal storage class`

Comment: @WhitAngl: As he said "it's only allowed since C++11, so if you are using older compiler it might not be available yet."  http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=ebbf0c8653cea8266485826982b25e8b-cc73e281b3b6abc9bf6cf4f153b944a6

Comment: does that mean there is just no solution that works for older C++, or just that this particular solution won't work for me ? thanks!

Comment: This particular solution will not work with older compiler. And even with a newer compiler, conversion marked `explicit` is really not that useful - it will work in above function because it directly requests conversion. And if you cannot use `explicit` then your problem can be stated as "You want to have a class that sometimes converts to `int` and sometimes it doesn't (eg. in your multiplication operators). I think that with some compromises you could still make it work, but it will get rather ugly.

Comment: For example, you could remove `operator*(MyClass, MyClass)`, and use multimplication with conversion to `int` - but I don't know if it even makes sense in your case. If it doesn't, there are still ways to deal with it, but the question is if it's actually worth doing.