# Return type in tempalte

Tags: c++, templates

I have a template class with the following method:

```
operator T*() const { 
    return (T*)foo();
  }
```

What does it return and how do I call this method?

Comment: It's a *conversion operator*. It's used to convert the object to `T*`.

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/cast_operator

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3008690/user-defined-conversions-in-c

Comment: You don't call it; it is called for you when a conversion to `T*` is required.

Comment: While you *normally* don't call it, it can be called just like any regular member function `object.operator T *()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a [user-defined conversion](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/cast_operator). This means that it converts the object of of your class template's instantiation to a different type implicitly. In this case the other type is `T*`.

Here is a contrived example:

```
template <typename T>
struct A {
  T* data;
  operator T*() const { // conversion to T*
    return data;
  }
};

int main() {
    int i = 42;
    A<int> a{&i};
    int* p = a; // A converts to int* via `operator int*()`
    // p points at i
}
```

The link above contains further examples and details.